# Capturing projector slides and audio at conference

Tags: audio-recording, screen-casting, recording, projector

I have a couple of events coming up for a professional conference where I need to be able to record all the 35 breakout rooms over 4 days (650 hours of footage) to capture the slides bring run from the computer to the projector and the audio from the soundboard in the convention center.

Since it is 450 sessions that have to be recorded and delivered within 3 days, I want to find a solution that means no real editing outside possible cropping the front and end of the recordings.

I am looking at some capture device that is self contained that I can pull feed split from the computer or projector and from the speaker that will simply record the feeds with the push of a button. This would allow me to have volunteers in the sessions start the recording potentially since I could not be in 35 places.

I am looking at the AJA HELO recorded and streamer or something similarly simple to start with input options as it would be used with different AV companies over the next couple of years. Are there any concerns there or recommendations for capture devices that are simple? It's just slides (no video) recording so audio is the larger quality factor.

I have video editing background, but the AV specs is something I am trying to learn more of.